# For ActiveMQ Artemis, how to separate the log message produced by LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin into different log file?

Tags: logging, activemq-artemis

I turn on LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin in order to record some information. But I don't want those information in artemis.log. I hope those information could be saved into a separated file so that I can manage it easily.

I know I should work with the file `logging.properties`, but I don't know how to configure the file. Could anybody provide a samlpe?

Appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need to do:

1. Add `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl` to the `loggers` list.
2. Direct `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl` to a new `handler`
3. Configure the new `handler` to point to a unique file.

For example, this configuration will direct output from the LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin to `logging_plugin.log` in the `log` directory next to `artemis.log`:

```
...
loggers=...,org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl
...
logger.org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl.level=ERROR
logger.org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl.handlers=LOGGING_PLUGIN
logger.org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl.useParentHandlers=false
...
handler.LOGGING_PLUGIN=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
handler.LOGGING_PLUGIN.level=DEBUG
handler.LOGGING_PLUGIN.properties=suffix,append,autoFlush,fileName
handler.LOGGING_PLUGIN.suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd
handler.LOGGING_PLUGIN.append=true
handler.LOGGING_PLUGIN.autoFlush=true
handler.LOGGING_PLUGIN.fileName=${artemis.instance}/log/logging_plugin.log
handler.LOGGING_PLUGIN.formatter=PATTERN
```

Comment: For adding the rotation function, I switch the handler to:
 `handler.LOGGING_PLUGIN=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicSizeRotatingFileHandler`. And add:
`handler.LOGGING_PLUGIN.properties=suffix,append,autoFlush,fileName,maxBackupIndex,rotateSize`,
`handler.LOGGING_PLUGIN.maxBackIndex=6`,
`handler.LOGGING_PLUGIN.rotateSize=1024000`,

but only maxBackIndex work. the property `rotateSize` does not work, nor is there any error message in artemis.log
The log file 'logging_plugin.log' always keeps around 655xxx bytes size. Could you please suggest some solutioon? Thanks